# I2C Bus With Conflicting Pullups

Tags: i2c

I am attempting to set up an I2C bus off of a Raspberry Pi that will have two slave devices. One of these devices already has built in pullup resistors, but the other does not. Is there any way to run them both on a single bus? Can I add a pullup resistor to the bus and expect them both to work? Or is this maybe something I can only figure out through testing?

Comment: Assuming the values are right (resistance vs bus capacitance and so on), you only need 1 resistor per line (SDA/SCL). Alternatively, its ok if there are many resistors in parallel as long as the parallel resistance is not too low so that the devices can't pull the bus down.

Comment: @WesleyLee: so assuming the resistance of the built in pullup is sufficient, communication with both should work as is? Thanks btw.

Comment: Yes as long as the wires are not too long. I'd say roughly/generally that if you take any 2 decent commercial breakouts there should be no issues using them together. Too many might be an issue but I find it hard to imagine that 2 pull ups (lets say 2k2~10k) will be too much for a RPi or Arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the I2C bus requires only two pull-ups, on SCLK and on SDA. If one of your devices has those pull-ups, then it may be just enough. You can look into RPi GPIO datasheet to see how much current it can sink (as well devices datasheet), therefore having two slave devices, each with its own pull-ups is not a good idea - the overall resistance can become too low, thus the bus current over max. allowable.